# Cannot access page object models from referenced project

Tags: nightwatch.js

I have a project **web.testing.dependent**, which refers to the page object models from **web.testing.referenced** project.

**web.testing.referenced** project has been packaged and published to the local registry and it is then  added as a dependency to **web.testing.dependent** project.

It is possible to import and access the elements of page object model in nightwatch tests, but it fails with the following error when the test is executed.

[image]

Below are the configuration details of the referenced project:

Nightwatch version: 3.3

tsconfig.json:

[image]

Appreciate any guidance on resolving this problem.

nightwatch.conf.js

[image]

In my case, in the dependent project I already have some page objects and want to refer page objects from reference projects which contains page objects which will be re-used by multiple different projects.
Alternatively, I also tried to use simple native JS classes (as drivers), which simply encapsulates driver functions

Comment: What is in the page objects section of your `nightwatch.conf.js`?

Comment: please see updated section @AutomatedTester